# Duplicate options exporting NFS share (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, nfs

Just tried to experiment a little with the issue described below. Deleted "rw" and "no_root_squash" options from the "/etc/exports" entry. In the output of "exportfs -v" I now see "ro" and "root_squash", but still, both are listed twice!
Anybody know where exportfs -v reads a list of options from?
If they are the correct options I would like to use, does it matter that they are listed twice???

Original post:
I am trying to share /storage directory to my local network computers.
The entry in /etc/exports is:

> /storage 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash,crossmnt)

I issue a command:

> sudo exportfs -a

and then the output of

> sudo exportfs -v

reads:

> /storage       192.168.1.0/24(rw,wdelay,crossmnt,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)

The contents of /var/lib/nfs/etab are:

> /storage   192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,crossmnt,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,sec=sys,rw,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)

What is going on? Why all the duplicate options? How can I get rid of the redundant ones? How can I get rid of unwanted ones like "hide"?

Answer (score 0):

You needed to `unexport` the directory. Try this

```
sudo exportfs -u /storage
sudo exportfs -u /storage
sudo exportfs /storage
```

When you checked the export list again you'll probably not see any duplicates.

Comment: Nope. I was unexporting and exporting again after making changes to `/etc/exports`. Tried also `sudo exportfs -ra`, same effect. Still duplicates. Note that my master export table at `/var/lib/nfs/etab` also contains the same duplicates. Again, they are the correct options I intended to be used, it is just the mystery that bugs me...